# How to reach ArrayList from getSerializable insted of Serializable?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

I'm put ArrayList into bundle:

```
private val data: ArrayList<MyDay> = arrayListOf()

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    fun submitData(data: List<MyDay>) {
        this.data.apply {
            clear()
            addAll(data)
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if (position < data.size) {
            DayWeatherFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putSerializable(FIVE_DAYS_DATA, data[position])
                }
            }
        } else Fragment()
    }
```

but when i'm trying to get it in my fragment:

```
val args = arguments?.getSerializable(FIVE_DAYS_DATA)

        args?.apply { }
```

I can't see fields in my array because it's type of Serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. To get Array you just need to put which type of data you want to get:

```
val args = arguments?.getSerializable(FIVE_DAYS_DATA) as MyDay
```